# Implicit search decision between multiple alternatives

Tags: scala, inheritance, typeclass, implicit

Is there any way of having multiple suitable alternatives in a type-class where the most specific is chosen, not producing diverging implicit expansion? It would look like this

```
trait A

trait B extends A

case class C extends B

trait Tester[-T] {def test (t : T) : Boolean}

object Tester{

  def test[T] (t : T)(implicit tester : Tester[T]) = tester.test(t)

  implicit def ATester = new Tester[A] {
    override def test (a : A) = true
  }

  implicit def BTester = new Tester[B] {
    override def test (b : B) = false
  }

}

val c = C()
Tester.test(c)
```

I want this to produce false as C is closer to B than to A in the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide some explanation about why this works the way this does - the other answer has a possible workaround.

The reason that `Tester[A]` gets picked over `Tester[B]` has to do with type `T` in `Tester[-T]` being contravariant. This means that for `Tester[A]` to be a subclass of `Tester[B]`, `A` must be a superclass of `B` - just like your code sample shows.

So when the method `test` (with the implicit parameter) requires a subtype of `Tester[C]`, the alternatives will be `Tester[B]` (subclass of `Tester[C]`) and `Tester[A]` (also subclass of `Tester[C]`, but a *more specific* one). This is why, according to the rule of choosing the most specific type, `Tester[A]` gets chosen.

If there was a `class D extends C`, and an implicit function that returns `Tester[D]`, if would not be a part of the resolution for parameter `Tester[C]`.

There's additional information about it [here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Implicit-Priorirty-with-Contravariant-Type-td1993358.html).

Comment: I get from your post that my example should work, right? But it does not. It complains about diverging expansion.

Comment: Your example compiles and runs without errors or warnings for me, under Scala 2.10.1 - what do you mean by "it complains"? And it is correct to chose Tester[A] and print true.

Comment: I can verify that it works on 2.10.1 and resolves to ATester. For allowing BTester to override ATester, try prioritizing your implicits according to @axel22's answer... which appears to now be gone. A pity, I think he had it right, but his BTester instance returned 'true'... Anyway, search for 'LowPriorityImplicits' and look at Predef for an example.

Comment: In the ScalaIde it was complaining but now I'm not able to reproduce it now. There are now other errors about ambiguous implicits but everything compiles so perhaps the original error was only a bug. The now gone answer looked promising but it seems it does exactly the same thing as with the flat object with implicits. I'm still not sure what is the proper way to achieve the behavior. I might have found the way though. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this helped

```
trait Tester[T] {def test (t : T) : Boolean}

object Tester{

  def test[T] (t : T)(implicit tester : Tester[T]) = tester.test(t)

  implicit def ATester[T <: A] = new Tester[T] {
    override def test (a : T) = true
  }

  implicit def BTester[T <: B] = new Tester[T] {
    override def test (b : T) = false
  }

}
```

Any objections?