# Scala: spec 6.23.3 implicit overloading resolution -- explanation needed

Tags: scala, implicit

This is a follow-up of [Implicit search decision between multiple alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044366/implicit-search-decision-between-multiple-alternatives). I'll quote the code from it.

```
trait A
trait B extends A
caseclass C extends B

trait Tester[-T] { def test (t: T): Boolean }
object Tester {
  def test[T](t : T)(implicit tester: Tester[T]) = tester.test(t)
  implicit def atester = new Tester[A] { override def test (a: A) = true }
  implicit def btester = new Tester[B] { override def test (b: B) = false }
}
val c = C()
Tester.test(c)
```

I understand conceptually why `atester: Tester[A]` is chosen over `btester: Tester[B]` when `Tester.test(implicit t: Tester[C])` is looking for implicit with respect to contravariance and specificity.

What I find difficult to see is how to concretely describe this in terms of spec `6.26.3 overloading resolution`.

AFAIK, the spec treats an identifier or selection e that needs overloading resolution in three categories:

1. e is used in a function application e(e1,..., e_m)
2. e is used in a type application e[targs]
3. otherwise

In addition, the spec describes the relative weight calculated by identifying one alternative is more specific than another.

I don't understand firstly which category to fit the alternatives to to. If they are `{ Tester[A], Tester[B] }`, then it seems to me (2) is likely but the rule for it --

> overloading resolution is applied again to the whole expression
>   e[targs]

-- looks throwing the ball back again. And I also fail to spot where in the spec states how to compare A and B.

---

A similar one: in the 2ed-ranked answer to the same question, the code is modified and I also quote it here:

```
trait Tester[T] {def test (t: T):Boolean }
object Tester{
  def test[T](t: T)(implicit tester: Tester[T]) = tester.test(t)
  implicit def atester[T <: A] = new Tester[T] { override def test (a: T) = true }
  implicit def btester[T <: B] = new Tester[T] { override def test (b: T) = false }
}
val c = C()
Tester.test(c)
```

I think the alternatives are the two polymorphic methods:
`{ atester[T <: A]: Tester[T], btester[T<: B]: Tester[T] }`. It looks fall in to the (1) category. But it's not clear for me to reason further.